# Doxygen generates xml output with different version

Tags: xml, output, version, doxygen

I'm using doxygen version 1.8.10.

> $ doxygen -version
>
> 1.8.10

However, the xml output files have another doxygen version.

`<doxygen xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="compound.xsd" version="1.6.1">`

Is there anyone who knows this problem?

Comment: When I run doxygen 1.8.10 on an further empty directory I get:xml/index.xml:<doxygenindex xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="index.xsd" version="1.8.10">  Do you have some special / own header type of files? What is the result when you use the newest (1.8.12) doxygen version? Can you create a small example showing the problem (at least the differences in your Doxyfile compared with the standard / default Doxyfile)?

Comment: @albert Thanks for your comment. The cause of this problem was that my PC had two different versions of doxygen executable on /usr/bin/doxygen (1.6.1) and /usr/local/bin/doxygen (1.8.10) respectively.